# Can't catch error from Graph requests (Blazor WASM)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, blazor-webassembly

I am unable to catch errors from when calling the Graph API.

Can anyone explain why I cannot catch the error? Simple example:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.Graph
@attribute [Authorize]
@inject GraphServiceClient GraphClient




@if (allUsers != null)
{
    foreach (var user in allUsers)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@user.DisplayName</td>
            <td>@user.Mail</td>
            <td>@user.UserPrincipalName</td>
        </tr>
    }
}

<h2>@errorMessage</h2>

@code {
    private string errorMessage = "No errors";

    private IEnumerable<Microsoft.Graph.User>? allUsers;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>
        {
            new QueryOption("$filter", "userType eq 'member1'") // causes a 400 error since member1 is not valid
        };
        try
        {
            //await Task.Delay(10000); // wait 10 seconds
            allUsers = await GraphClient.Users.Request(queryOptions).GetAsync();

        }
        catch (ServiceException ex) // using catch (Exception ex) also doesn't work
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error getting users from Graph: " + ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Error code: " + ex.Error.Code);
            Console.WriteLine("Error inner message: " + ex.Error.InnerError.Message);

            // Show error message to the user or log the error
            errorMessage = "An error occurred while trying to get users from the Microsoft Graph API.";
        }
        Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

When debugging it just skips over the catch block so it is not being triggered, and no errors are written the console. I know what the error is (using an invalid queryOption), I can see the error details in browser dev tools.

Comment: When you get a status code result of 400, that isn't a csharp exception, its a status code returned from the server.

Comment: The Graph SDK should throw a service exception I believe...https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-core/blob/9c89457f9215a691396f44fd85ef7e89e93f91d5/src/Microsoft.Graph.Core/Exceptions/ServiceException.cs

Comment: That's not an error being raised in your code, it is being raised in their code.

Comment: 400 is client-side error, I would recommend you to test the same API call in POSTMAN to make sure you are passing correct values. Looking at your code it looks like you are using filter as Memebe1 where you should be using Member as userType https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$$filter=userType eq 'Member' something similar to this.

Comment: Yes thanks, I'm deliberately using an invalid filter, as I want to be able to detect this in code. For example, I will be dynamically building filters so need to be able to easily show an error with digging around in F12 dev tools. So if this is an HTTP status code, how can I catch this in the response and then display that to the user? I just need it in a variable.